# preserving original values in ggradar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using [ggradar](https://rdrr.io/github/ricardo-bion/ggradar/man/ggradar-package.html) to create radar plots. I have a case like this:

```
library(ggradar)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(tibble)

animal <- c("lion","tiger","elephant")
strength <- c(80,70,100)
speed <- c(70,100,50)
power <- c(60,50,100)
anger <- c(90,60,40)
data <- data.frame(animal,strength,speed,power,anger)
att <- c("strength","speed","power","anger")
animals <- c("elephant","tiger","lion")
data <- data[, c("animal",att)]
plot.data <- data[which(data$animal %in% animals),]
as_tibble(plot.data)

data_radar <- plot.data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-animal), rescale)

p <- ggradar(data_radar, 
             legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~group)

print(p)
```

[image]

Is it possible to plot the radars in a such a way that preserves the original values, which are all scores out of 100? So, for example, the scores for elephant would be plotted as 100, 50, 100 and 40, for strength, speed, power and anger respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by setting the argument `grid.max` and `grid.mid` You could also set the labels via `values.radar`:

```r
library(ggradar)
library(ggplot2)

ggradar(plot.data, 
             legend.position = "none", values.radar = c("0", "50", "100"), grid.max = 100, grid.mid = 50) +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]